# Data retrieval using dapper with ASP.NET Core C#

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, dapper

I am facing a problem while fetching SQL Server data using ASP.NET Core with Dapper method.

I have a views with 3 `varbinary(max)` columns with 800 records, which executes under 2 seconds in SSMS.

But in .NET Core, it is taking around 1 minute to return the result.

Please see Dapper data access methods I tried below.

Method 1:

```
var data = await connection.QueryMultipleAsync(command);
```

Method 2:

```
var data = await connection.QueryAsync<ModelName>(command);
```

Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Which is the fastest Dapper method to fetch `varbinary(max)` data with same time as in SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that they should not have any difference in performance, and since they have, there must be something else happening, but it is not possible to tell what as you haven't provided a repro of the problem.

If you are new to Dapper, my recommendation is to take a look a this tutorial I wrote. You'll get your answers: https://medium.com/dapper-net/multiple-executions-56c410e9f8dd

The full tutorial is here: https://medium.com/dapper-net/dapper-net-tutorial-summary-79125c8ecdb2